# $D_{\infty}$ acts on the real line as the group generated by (affine) reflections across two distinct points.

Tags: geometric-group-theory

I feel confused about the meaning of "$D_{\infty}$ acts on the real line as the group generated by (affine) reflections across two distinct points."

where $D_{\infty} = \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}\ast \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$

1 What are the reflections across two distinct points (I am asking the definition, I don't understand what a reflection across two distinct points is)?

2 How to see the group generated by (affine) reflections across two distinct points is just $D_{\infty}$?

Comment: I could very well be mistaken, but I think even though it says "acts on the real line," this action isn't transitive, so that seems a bit misleading. $D_\infty$ (as I understand it) only acts transitively on $\Bbb Z$ (or a subset "like" $\Bbb Z$).

Comment: @pjs36 thanks, do you know what the reflections across two distinct points are?

Comment: You'll get something isomorphic to $D_\infty$ no matter what points you choose, but there are lots of copies of $D_\infty$ living in the isometry group of the real line. Or are you asking something more along the lines of, "How does that work, I'm not even sure how to work with reflections like that" ?

Comment: @pjs36 I am asking the definition of the reflections across two distinct points.

Comment: Ah, I see (maybe). I think they mean "pick two points $a, b \in \Bbb R$, and consider (separately!) the reflections $r_a$ and $r_b$ across $a$ and $b$." For formulas, we have $r_a(x) = -(x - a) + a = 2a - x$, and likewise for $r_b(x)$.

Comment: @pjs36 Now I am totally clear with my question. Thanks!